# SVN Server error

Tags: svn

We are using SVN version 1.6.17 in Debian, we are getting the following error when a user tries to
checkout/update a SVN resource

```
[Thu Jan 30 10:17:44 2014] [error] [client 192.168.5.147] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]   
[Thu Jan 30 10:17:44 2014] [error] [client 192.168.5.147] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #185005]  
[Thu Jan 30 10:17:44 2014] [error] [client 192.168.5.147] Decompression of svndiff data failed  [500, #185005]
```

Comment: Did it ever work without errors or is it new installation?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting svn service resolved this error.
svn could successfully update or checkout code.

Answer (score -1):

This error is probably caused by a commit that failed halfway, leaving it in an invalid state.

Use svnadmin to find the offending commit:

```
svnadmin verify /path/to/repos
```

it will run through each and every commit starting at 0 through HEAD

- Verified revision 418.
- Verified revision 419.
  svnadmin: Decompression of svndiff data failed

You can try to use [fsfsverify](http://www.szakmeister.net/fsfsverify/) to fix your repository. fsfsverify exists in Subversion’s contrib area (contrib/server-side/fsfsverify.py).

***NOTE: Backup your repository. fsfverify may corrupt it.***

```
fsfsverify.py -f /path/to/repos/db/revs/419
```

Where *419* is the corrupted revision. So replace that number with the actual corrupted revision you got from svnadmin verify.

---

Another option you could try is to delete the files in the offending commit from HEAD. You can commit these files again later.

Comment: * Verified revision 0.
* Verified revision 1.
* Verified revision 2.
* Verified revision 3.
* Verified revision 4.
svnadmin: Decompression of svndiff data failed

Comment: Ok, then as I suggested in the answer: backup your repo and run fsfsverify.py (../db/revs/4)

Comment: while running ./fsfsverify.py /home/subversion/php/db/revs/0/4